# bashでコマンドの実行結果を標準出力に出しつつクリップボードにコピーする

Tags: windows, bash, mingw

以下のようにすればコマンドの実行結果を標準出力とファイルの両方に出力できますが、同じように「コマンドの実行結果を標準出力に出力しつつ、クリップボードにコピーする」ということはできないでしょうか。

```
command | tee output.txt
```

環境はWindows上のgit bashです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: OS依存ですがクリップボードにアクセスできるコマンドやデバイスがあります https://stackoverflow.com/a/750466/1514010

Comment: 大前提としてクリップボードはOS・プラットホームに依存します。どのような環境で実行することを想定されていますでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。Windows上のgit bashで実行することを想定しています。

Comment: 別環境の話なので余談になりますが， `PowerShell` なら `> command |scb; gcb` ，`macOS` なら `$ command |pbcopy; pbpaste` でも出来そうです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows環境とのことですので [`clip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clip) を使うことになります。使い方はoririさんの回答通り、`tee`で内容を別ファイルに書き出しつつ標準出力しますが、その際、[bashのプロセス置換機能](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)を使い別ファイルでなく別プロセスに出力します。

```
$ echo -e 'hello\nworld' | tee >(clip)
hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

bash であれば次のように

```bash
$ echo -e 'hello\nworld' | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)
hello
world
```

#### 追記

回答した時点では実行環境が記されていなかったので
「**コマンドの実行結果を標準出力に出力しつつ**、クリップボードにコピーする」の例として, 上記では X11環境で使えるはずのクリップボード取得コマンドを記しています
(`xclip -selection clipboard` の部分)

Linux各種ディストリその他や macOS その他の環境でのクリップボード取得コマンドは「[クリップボードにコピーしたweb上の表を...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61533/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fweb%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E3%82%92%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8A%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92python%E3%81%A7%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/78149#78149)」が参考にできるかも

Windows環境では DLL扱うようなので, 標準的なクリップボード取得コマンドが用意されているのならそちらを使うとよいでしょう。
コマンドが用意されていない場合は, 先の回答に示すコードからクリップボード取得コマンド自作することにするかもです